# SSH Terminal in Browser in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh

I've taken a look at the Net-SSH gem, but it doesn't seem to support the in browser aspect.  Before I start integrating that gem with javascript and a full user interface, I just wanted to ask the community if there are any libraries that have done this for me already.  Feel free to suggest libraries outside of ruby.  Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to do? Do you want to execute open up SSH connection inside your browser and run commands?

Answer (score 1):

There is already a product: [GateOne](http://liftoffsoftware.com/Products/GateOne). But sorry it is Python.